# Derived Equivalence for Topological spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology

We sometimes want to know when two Abelian categories $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ are "similar", and the usual notion is the equivalence of categories. This may be too demanding and we sometimes ask for a (triangulated) equivalence between $D(\mathscr{A})$ and $D(\mathscr{B})$. This seems to be used to understand representations of groups/algebras/quivers. My questions is about the same problem, but applied to topological spaces.

For any topological space $X$, one may create a topos $\operatorname{Sh}(X)$. As is well-known, [$X$ may be recovered from its category of sheaves if it is sober](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sheaf+on+a+topological+space#localic_reflection). Usually, we are interested only in the homological informations of a topological space, and so it seems natural to study $D(X) := D(\operatorname{Ab}(X))$, so my question is the following: if two sober spaces $X$ and $Y$ are derived equivalent (i.e. $D(X) \cong D(Y)$), what is the relation between $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Sober topological spaces are not Hausdorff  and I don't think that topological information of the sober space itself would be interesting. In algebraic geometry the interesting homological information is in the etale topos which needs more data then the  underlying sober topological space $X$. Still I think the question is intersting.